# find the marginal density

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, density-function

Suppose that random variables $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ have a joint probability density function
$$f(y_1,y_2)=6y_1^2y_2$$
with $0 \leq y_1 \leq y_2,y_1 + y_2 \leq2$.

I am trying to find the marginal density function of $Y_2$. So far, I have
$$
f_{Y_2}(y_2)=\int_{0}^{y_2}f(y_1, y_2)dy_1=\int_{0}^{y_2}6y_1^2y_2dy_1=2y_2^4
$$
with $0\leq y_2\leq 1$

But the integral of $f_{Y_2}(y_2)$ from $0$ to $1$ is not one. I believe I did something wrong.

Comment: The upper limit of integration should be $\min\{y_2, 2-y_2\}$.

Comment: The joint density itself doesn't seem to integrate to $1$ on the given region either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @angryavian
\begin{align*}
                f_{Y_2}(y_2)&=\int_{0}^{\min\{y_2,2-y_2\}}f(y_1, y_2)dy_1\\
                &=
                \begin{cases}
                \int_{0}^{y_2}6y_1^2y_2dy_1&\hspace{5mm}0\leq y_2\leq 1\\
                \int_{0}^{2-y_2}6y_1^2y_2dy_1&\hspace{5mm}1\leq y_2\leq 2
                \end{cases}\\
                &=
                \begin{cases}
                2y_2^4&\hspace{5mm}0\leq y_2\leq 1\\
                -2(y_2-2)^3y_2&\hspace{5mm}1\leq y_2\leq 2
                \end{cases}
            \end{align*}

the integral is one
$$\int_{0}^{1}2y_2^4dy_2+\int_{1}^{2}-2(y_2-2)^3y_2dy_2=1$$